# Python 3 Import Error: No module named 'RPi'

Tags: gpio

I am currently following the CamJam EduKit 3 - Robotics tutorial and I've hit a minor snag.

I keep getting this error when I try to execute my program

`ImportError: No module named 'RPi'`.

I have tried everything I know from using pip and update to various other methods.

I am using a Pi Zero with the most current version of Stretch Lite.

You can find the tutorial I am following [here](https://github.com/CamJam-EduKit/EduKit3/raw/master/CamJam%20EduKit%203%20-%20Robotics%20Worksheet%203%20-%20Running%20the%20Motors.pdf).

Comment: Not necessarily, @Fabian; as the RPi Python module is ["software *specific* to the Pi"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (i.e. you probably aren't running it anywhere else), it seems on-topic to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution! You have to install RPi.GPIO via pip3 not just pip.
If anyone has any questions on how I did this let me know and I'll help you out!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3 you need to use a Python 3 version of modules.

pip downloads Python 2 modules.

To download Python 3 modules use pip3.